# DrawToBitmap - A generic error occurred in GDI+

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, drawtobitmap

I'm trying to capture a screenshot from a flash object in my windows forms form.

When I try to do this and debug, I get the exception `A generic error occurred in GDI+.` on the `bmp.Save`... line.

However what seems to be responsible is `DrawToBitmap`. Trying to set a picture-box image to this screenshot gives the exception `Parameter is not valid`.

I've also tried using `Form.ActiveForm.DrawToBitmap` instead but that seems to be doing the same thing... I have no clue what the problem could be at this point.

```
pictureBox1.Image = CaptureScreenshot();

// Capture screenshot of the form
private Bitmap CaptureScreenshot()
{
    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(500, 500))
    {
        axShockwaveFlash1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 500));
        bmp.Save(@"c:\screenshot.png");
        return bmp;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Just a thought. Your app doesn't have write access to the route of the C drive. It certainly shouldn't have anyway. See if you can save it to a more accessible location. MyPictures would be a better choice, yo can get that using the Environment.SpecialFolder enumeration

Comment: You are returning a disposed bitmap.  Get rid of the *using* statement.

Comment: Removing the using statement and only keeping the `var bmp = new Bitmap(500, 500);` still gives the same exception :/

Comment: Also nope, writing permission shouldn't be the problem, since removing the bmp.Save and allowing the `pictureBox1.Image = CaptureScreenshot();` also seems to return an invalid Bitmap